# Issue with eloquent an relashionship many to many in laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I started to learn laravel 1 month ago and I have the next issue.
I have 2 models, user and role and they have M to N relationship, therefore I have 3 tables.

```
Class Role          Class Role_User                  Class User
===========         ===============                  =========== 
id | name          id | user_id | role_id          id | name  | lastname
1     ADMIN         1      1          1             1   John     Rambo
2     AUTOR         2      1          2  
3     USER
```

In the models I have the next code

```
Model User

public function roles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
  }

Model Role

public function users()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

I need in my view to list all user with role ADMIN and I dont know waht code I need to put.

```
public function index($type)
    {
      $users = Role::all()->roles()->where('name', 'ADMIN');
      return view('admin.user.list', compact('users'));
    }
```

Could you help me pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a result composed of users, you need to launch your query on them. And dont forget to run the query with `get()` (this case), `first()`, `find(..)`....

```php
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($role) {
    $role->where('name','ADMIN');
})->get();
return view('admin.user.list', compact('users'));
```